# Website produces 404 error unless a valid path is specified after it

Tags: url, web

I'm not quite sure how to Google this problem, so here I am. I recently purchased a domain, set everything up, got a free host, etc. However, whenever I access the URL on its own, without a path, I'm brought my webhost's 404 page. When I access the URL with a valid path specified, I get the page I was looking for. Meaning, www.example.com -> 404. www.example.com/index.html -> the page I'm actually trying to go to.

I've been digging all over cPanel (my host is 000webhost for lack of funds) and I couldn't find anything out of the ordinary. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change the directory indexes because index.php is defualt

```
1. Mmber Area of 000webhost
2. File Manager -> log in
3. open public_html
4. Edit .htaccess 
5.Let the .htacces look like that:



# Do not remove this line, otherwise mod_rewrite rules will stop working
RewriteBase /

DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

So when you open the Directory(what http://example.com/ is)
it will search first for index.php, then for index.html and open that if found.

Comment: Is there any particular place I should put that line? I tested it in a couple of places and it still resulted in a 404.

Comment: I mean, I placed within .htaccess and it did not change anything. Should appear at the top of the file or is that unimportant?

Comment: this should not be important, but at the end of file would be fine.
If there are any other DirectoryIndex lines in that file, delete them

Comment: Interesting. Unfortunately, this seems to have no effect. neither the default or /index.php redirect to /index.html and still result in 404 pages.

Comment: can you show the code of the .htacces and maybe a directory listing of public_html

Comment: `# Do not remove this line, otherwise mod_rewrite rules will stop working`
`RewriteBase /`
`# DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE AND THE LINES BELOW REDIRECTID:HRVkpy`
`RewriteEngine on`
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^wakef.org$ [OR]`
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.wakef.org$`
`RewriteRule ^$ http://wakef.org/index.php [R=301,L]`
`# DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE AND THE LINES ABOVE HRVkpy:REDIRECTID`
`DirectoryIndex index.php index.html`

Apologies, I can't quite seem to get the code tags to work.

[this](http://i.imgur.com/yb0IwYF.png) is my public_html/ folder.

Comment: hmm, sry im out, no clue

Comment: That's alright. I appreciate the help nonetheless. Thanks, man.